# Heap memory not freeing less than 1200 mb after GC alloted heap space is 2048 mb

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jboss-eap-6

Iam running a Jboss EAP server 6.1 in Linux box.
The Allocated Heap memory is  AS below.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

When the garbage collection happens the heap memory is not freeing less than 1200 mb,and is leading to out of memory error.

Attached GC report below.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7junC5UmfFgVDQ5NjM2ZjVpSms

Would like to understand GC better,any help appreciated.

Comment: The link is broken. Attach the information from the reports in the question here itself..

Answer (score 2):

Your old generation is full and remains full after full GCs. That either means the heap size is too small (increase Xmx or optimize your application to work with less memory) or your application is leaking (take a heap dump, look for objects that exist but shouldn't).